# Fast sampling from a user-defined distribution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, probability, random

A simulation I'm running requires me to draw values from a probability distribution.  I'm doing this as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.special as sp
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous


class epsilon_pdf(rv_continuous):

    def _pdf(self, x, omega):

        return np.exp(omega ** -1 * np.cos(x)) / (2 * np.pi *
                                                  sp.iv(0, omega ** -1))


random_epsilon = epsilon_pdf(a=-np.pi, b=np.pi)
n_trials = 1  # 10 ** 6
goal_dict = {'omega': 2 ** -4, 'xi': 2 ** 0}
for trial_num in xrange(n_trials):
    # Choose m.
    m = np.random.poisson(goal_dict['xi'])
    # Draw m values for epsilon.
    epsilon_values = random_epsilon.rvs(omega=goal_dict['omega'], size=m)
```

(What's written above is a minimal toy example.)

A major problem I've encountered is that the call to `random_epsilon.rvs` is incredibly slow -- so slow that when I set `n_trials` to the needed `10 ** 6`, certain values of `omega` and `xi` cause the script to take upwards of 377 hours to finish.

Can anyone think of a reformulation in Python code of my probability distribution and my sampling from it that would be faster?  (Perhaps there is a way to do this using numpy that would be faster?)

(I'm not sure whether my distribution is a standard one that has been given a name.)

Comment: If your code is working, perhaps you should be at http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @zondo is there a way to migrate this there?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a way, but I've never done it, so I couldn't tell you how.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises_distribution, implemented as scipy.stats.vonmises

Comment: also implemented as `numpy.random.vonmises`.  it would seem to be the case that numpy is generally faster for random sampling than is scipy.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous
import scipy.special as sp
import time
from numpy import ma as ma

class epsilon_pdf(rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x, omega):
        return np.exp(omega ** -1 * np.cos(x)) / (2 * np.pi *
                                                  sp.iv(0, omega ** -1))

random_epsilon = epsilon_pdf(a=-np.pi, b=np.pi)
n_trials = 1000  # 10 ** 6
goal_dict = {'omega': 2 ** -4, 'xi': 2 ** 0}

random_epsilon_rvs = lambda x: random_epsilon.rvs(
    omega=goal_dict['omega'], 
    size = x
    )

random_epsilon_rvs = np.vectorize(random_epsilon_rvs, otypes=[np.ndarray])

t0 = time.time()
for trial_num in xrange(n_trials):
    # Choose m.
    m = np.random.poisson(goal_dict['xi'])
    # Draw m values for epsilon.
    epsilon_values = random_epsilon.rvs(omega=goal_dict['omega'], size=m)

t1 = time.time()
a = np.random.poisson(2**-4, size = (1, n_trials))[0]
mask = a>0
b = a[mask]
c = random_epsilon_rvs(b)

t2 = time.time()

print t1-t0,t2-t1
# 11.7730000019 vs 0.682999849319
```

Comment: which line throws the exception?

Comment: and are you sure this is giving you the correct result?  the `a` you're passing to `random_epsilon_rvs` is an array.  my guess is what you're getting for `b` is an N-D array, where N equals the number of elements in `a`.  that's not what is desired, and not what the code in my question produces.

Comment: i had the insight to pull `random_epsilon.rvs` out of the `for` loop in parallel with you, but for me it makes *no difference* for timing.  requesting `size=m` from `random_epsilon.rvs` `n` times in a `for` loop is equivalent for me to calling `random_epsilon.rvs` just one time with `size=(n, m)`.  is that not the case for you?

Comment: you're correct. I absolutely forgot a step... which was to vectorize the callable.

Note. I use a mask because for all the 0's you get back an empty array and thats just a waste. But the time is pretty much exactly the same even without a mask. I modified the code to use the newer version. It offers what seems to be a 1 fold increase. You'll have to test it out yourself. 

Hope this helps.

Comment: some aspects of this are still opaque to me.  for example, why pass `size=(1, n_trials)` to `np.random.poisson` as opposed to `size=n_trials`?  because the comments under my question are conceptually straightforward and fully resolve the speed issue, i'm not motivated to try to decipher your logic or confirm that the results of your method are the same as the results of the code in my question.

Comment: Absolutely up to you. But let me explain what I'm doing in case a similar approach helps you the next time. The lambda is straightforward - it just binds one kw-arg transforming the function into 1in -> 1out. The vectorize provide a callable that works on every element on a numpy array. So that way when you do f(np.array) is actually does f(x) for x in np.array.

There is no difference between using size=(1, n_trials))[0] and just doing size=n_trials. I was messing around and wanted to see if assigning the shape would make it run faster. It didn't and I forgot to remove it. Have fun with np :)